# Paypal Express Checkout correct flow

Tags: javascript, cordova, paypal, recurring-billing

I'm developing an Ionic Phonegap application (Marketplace selling applications online), I have implemented Express Checkout following these two flows

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-basicDigGoodsPayment-curl-etc/ (for normal payments)

and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/ (for recurring payments)

For recurring payments they have shown 5 steps

1. Set Up the Payment Authorization (setting required parameters and hitting `SetExpressCheckout` method)
2. Redirect the Customer to PayPal for Authorization
3. Obtain Customer Details (setting required parameters and hitting `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` method) this is optional but still I have hit it
4. Create the Recurring Payments Profile (setting required parameters and hitting `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method)
5. Review the Recurring Payments Profile (Optional)

**The Question** Do I need to hit `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` after or before `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`?

**Note:** In `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` I have set `PROFILESTARTDATE` parameter to now, will this deduct the first payment from buyers profile immediately?

Following is the code of my `SetExpressCheckout` function

```
var SetExpressCheckoutForRecurrence = function SetExpressCheckoutForRecurrence( itemName ) {

  var formData = {};

  formData['USER'] = PAYPAL.USERNAME;
  formData['PWD'] = PAYPAL.PASSWORD;
  formData['SIGNATURE'] = PAYPAL.SIGNATURE;

  formData['METHOD'] = PAYPAL.METHOD_EXPRESS_CHECKOUT;                                // SetExpressCheckout
  formData['VERSION'] = PAYPAL.VERSION;                                               //86

  formData['L_BILLINGTYPE0'] = PAYPAL.BILLINGTYPE;
  formData['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] = PAYPAL.BILLING_AGREEMENT_DESCRIPTION + ' for ' + itemName;

  formData['cancelUrl'] = PAYPAL.CANCEL_URL;
  formData['returnUrl'] = PAYPAL.RETURN_URL;
  formData['notifyUrl'] = BASEURL.LIVE + PAYPAL.NOTIFY_URL;

  return formData;
}
```

and `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` function

```
var queryParam = {};
  queryParam['USER'] = PAYPAL.USERNAME;
  queryParam['PWD'] = PAYPAL.PASSWORD;
  queryParam['SIGNATURE'] = PAYPAL.SIGNATURE;

  queryParam['METHOD'] = PAYPAL.METHOD_RECURRENCE_CHECKOUT;
  queryParam['VERSION'] = PAYPAL.VERSION;

  queryParam['TOKEN'] = token;
  queryParam['PAYERID'] = payerId;

  queryParam['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = new Date().toISOString();
  queryParam['DESC'] = desc;
  queryParam['BILLINGPERIOD'] = period;
  queryParam['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = frequency;
  queryParam['AMT'] = amount;
  queryParam['CURRENCYCODE'] = PAYPAL.CURRENCY;
  queryParam['COUNTRYCODE'] = PAYPAL.COUNTRY_CODE;
  queryParam['MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS'] = PAYPAL.FAILED_ATTEMPS;

  var params = objToParam(queryParam);
  var url = PAYPAL.NVP_URL + params;

  Api.get(url).then(function successResponse (response){

    var responseObj = unserialize(response);
    console.log('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Success', responseObj);
    if ( responseObj.ACK === 'Success' && responseObj.PROFILESTATUS === "ActiveProfile" ) {

      processIPN( custom, null, amount, 'subscr_payment' );
    }

  }, function failResponse (response) {

    console.log('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Fail', response);
  });
}
```